# Are multiple redirects within an AND-OR list valid in POSIX shell syntax?

Tags: shell, posix, grammar

I want to know if using redirects within an [AND-OR list](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_09_03) is valid POSIX shell syntax.

```
if cat foo > foo.txt && cat bar > bar.txt
then
    echo true
else
    echo false
fi
```

I have been reading the [Shell Grammar Rules](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_10) to determine this but I am not quite sure if I have understood it correctly.

This is what I have understood so far.

```
if_clause        : If compound_list Then compound_list else_part Fi
                 | If compound_list Then compound_list           Fi
                 ;
```

Therefore, for my code sample to be a valid `if_clause`, `cat foo > foo.txt && cat bar > bar.txt` must be `compound_list`.

```
compound_list    :              term
                 | newline_list term
                 |              term separator
                 | newline_list term separator
                 ;
```

Therefore, for `cat foo > foo.txt && cat bar > bar.txt` to be a valid `compound_list`, it must also be a `term`.

```
term             : term separator and_or
                 |                and_or
                 ;

newline_list     :              NEWLINE
                 | newline_list NEWLINE
                 ;

linebreak        : newline_list
                 | /* empty */
                 ;

separator_op     : '&'
                 | ';'
                 ;

separator        : separator_op linebreak
                 | newline_list
                 ;
```

Since there is no `separator` in `cat foo > foo.txt && cat bar > bar.txt`, for it to be a valid `term`, it must be a valid `and_or`.

```
%token  AND_IF    OR_IF    DSEMI
/*      '&&'      '||'     ';;'    */

and_or           :                         pipeline
                 | and_or AND_IF linebreak pipeline
                 | and_or OR_IF  linebreak pipeline
                 ;
```

There is `AND_IF` in `cat foo > foo.txt && cat bar > bar.txt`, so let us see if `cat foo > foo.txt && cat bar > bar.txt` matches `and_or AND_IF linebreak pipeline`.

For `cat foo > foo.txt && cat bar > bar.txt` to be a valid `and_or AND_IF linebreak pipeline`, `cat foo > foo.txt` must be a valid `and_or` and `cat bar > bar.txt` must be a valid `pipeline`.

Since there is no further `AND_IF` in `cat foo > foo.txt`, for it to be an `and_or`, it must also be a `pipeline`.

In other words, for `cat foo > foo.txt && cat bar > bar.txt` to be a valid `and_or AND_IF linebreak pipeline`, both `cat foo > foo.txt` and `cat bar > bar.txt` must be valid `pipeline`s.

Now, let us see if we can prove `cat foo > foo.txt` as a valid `pipeline`. If we can do so, then `cat bar > bar.txt` would also be proven as a valid `pipeline` because they are similar in construct.

```
%token  Lbrace    Rbrace    Bang
/*      '{'       '}'       '!'   */

pipeline         :      pipe_sequence
                 | Bang pipe_sequence
                 ;
```

Since `cat foo > foo.txt` doesn't have `!` in it, for it to be a valid `pipeline`, it must also be a valid `pipe_sequence`.

```
pipe_sequence    :                             command
                 | pipe_sequence '|' linebreak command
                 ;
```

Since `cat foo > foo.txt` doesn't have `|` in it, for it to be a valid `pipeline_sequence`, it must also be a valid `command`.

```
command          : simple_command
                 | compound_command
                 | compound_command redirect_list
                 | function_definition
                 ;

function_definition : fname '(' ')' linebreak function_body
                     ;

%token  If    Then    Else    Elif    Fi    Do    Done
/*      'if'  'then'  'else'  'elif'  'fi'  'do'  'done'   */

%token  Case    Esac    While    Until    For
/*      'case'  'esac'  'while'  'until'  'for'   */
%token  Lbrace    Rbrace    Bang
/*      '{'       '}'       '!'   */

brace_group      : Lbrace compound_list Rbrace
                 ;

subshell         : '(' compound_list ')'
                 ;

for_clause       : For name linebreak                            do_group
                 | For name linebreak in          sequential_sep do_group
                 | For name linebreak in wordlist sequential_sep do_group
                 ;

if_clause        : If compound_list Then compound_list else_part Fi
                 | If compound_list Then compound_list           Fi
                 ;

while_clause     : While compound_list do_group
                 ;

until_clause     : Until compound_list do_group
                 ;
```

Since `cat foo > foo.txt` doesn't have `{`, `(`, `for`, `case`, `if`, `while`, or `until`, it cannot be `compound_command redirect_list`, `compound_command redirect_list` or `function_definition`. Therefore, for `cat foo > foo.txt` to a valid `command`, it must be a valid `simple_command`.

```
simple_command   : cmd_prefix cmd_word cmd_suffix
                 | cmd_prefix cmd_word
                 | cmd_prefix
                 | cmd_name cmd_suffix
                 | cmd_name
                 ;
%token  DLESS  DGREAT  LESSAND  GREATAND  LESSGREAT  DLESSDASH
/*      '<<'   '>>'    '<&'     '>&'      '<>'       '<<-'   */


%token  CLOBBER
/*      '>|'   */

cmd_prefix       :            io_redirect
                 | cmd_prefix io_redirect
                 |            ASSIGNMENT_WORD
                 | cmd_prefix ASSIGNMENT_WORD

io_redirect      :           io_file
                 | IO_NUMBER io_file
                 |           io_here
                 | IO_NUMBER io_here
                 ;

io_file          : '<'       filename
                 | LESSAND   filename
                 | '>'       filename
                 | GREATAND  filename
                 | DGREAT    filename
                 | LESSGREAT filename
                 | CLOBBER   filename
                 ;

io_here          : DLESS     here_end
                 | DLESSDASH here_end
                 ;
```

Since `cat foo > foo.txt` does not begin with `IO_NUMBER` (digits), `io_file` (redirection symbols), `<<-`, `<<-`, or `ASSIGNMENT_WORD` (`=` in the first `WORD`), it cannot be `cmd_prefix cmd_word cmd_suffix`, `cmd_prefix cmd_word` or `cmd_prefix`.

Therefore, for `cat foo > foo.txt` to be a valid `simple_command`, it must be `cmd_name cmd_suffix`.

Since `cmd_name` is defined as `WORD`, for `cat foo > foo.txt` to be a valid command, `foo > foo.txt` must be `cmd_suffix`.

```
cmd_suffix       :            io_redirect
                 | cmd_suffix io_redirect
                 |            WORD
                 | cmd_suffix WORD
                 ;
```

For `foo > foo.txt` to be a valid `cmd_suffix`, `foo` must be a valid `cmd_suffix` and `> foo.txt` be a valid `io_redirect`.

Indeed `foo` is a valid `cmd_suffix` because it is a valid `WORD`.

```
io_redirect      :           io_file
                 | IO_NUMBER io_file
                 |           io_here
                 | IO_NUMBER io_here
                 ;
```

For `> foo.txt` to be valid `io_redirect` it must be a valid `io_file`.

```
io_file          : '<'       filename
                 | LESSAND   filename
                 | '>'       filename
                 | GREATAND  filename
                 | DGREAT    filename
                 | LESSGREAT filename
                 | CLOBBER   filename
                 ;
```

For `> foo.txt` to be valid `io_file`, `foo.txt` must be a valid `filename`.

```
filename         : WORD                      /* Apply rule 2 */
                 ;
```

Indeed `foo.txt` is a valid `filename` because it is a valid `WORD`. This proves that `cat foo > foo.txt` is a valid `simple_command`, and therefore, `cat foo > foo.txt && cat bar > bar.txt` is a valid `and_or` and therefore, the code sample I provided is a valid `if_clause`.

Am I correct?

Answer (score 2):

You claim that:

> … there is no `AND_IF` or `OR_IF` in `cat foo > foo.txt && cat bar > bar.txt`

But there clearly is, since `AND_IF` is the name of the token <kbd>&&</kbd>. The operands of that operator are pipelines, which may be simple commands including redirections. So the expression is perfectly valid.

**Edit:** Now that the question has been edited, this answer is almost meaningless (or at least requires an investigation of revision history). As far as I can see, the reasoning in the revised question is correct.

Comment: Thanks! That was a serious mistake in my question. I have fixed my question and worked the whole thing out once again and it indeed seems like a valid `if_clause` but I would like someone to check my derivation and confirm if it is correct.

Comment: @LoneLearner: Since the construct works on any shell, it seems like human confirmation is somewhat redundant, but I edited my answer to provide some.